# What happens if the only Domain Controller in a AD Site fails

Tags: active-directory

I have a Domain environment say abc.com
This has 2 sites Site1 and Site2.
Site1 has 3 DCs in it while Site2 only has 1 DC.

The question is what happens if the only DC in Site2 fails?
Will the clients in Site2 be provided AD Services by the DCs of Site1 or face authentication and other AD related issues?

PS : By fails, I mean a irrecoverable hardware or OS crash.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Site 2 client's DNS is configured correctly with a secondary DNS server in Site 1, it should use DC's in Site 1 if DC's in Site 2 are unavailable.